# A OOD design question, how to elegantly avoid repeated definitions of similar class attributes

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I have a problem, I enum with several types of certain object

```
class Type(Enum):
    TYPE_A
    TYPE_B
    TYPE_C
    TYPE_D
     ....
```

```
class Something():
    def __init__(self):
        self.TYPE_A_list = []
        self.TYPE_B_list = []
        self.TYPE_C_list = []
        self.TYPE_D_list = []
        ...


    def add_data(self, type: Type, value: int):
        if type == TYPE_A:
            self.TYPE_A_list.append(value)
        elif type == TYPE_B:
            self.TYPE_A_list.append(value)
        elif type == TYPE_C:
            self.TYPE_A_list.append(value)
        elif type == TYPE_D:
            self.TYPE_A_list.append(value)
        ....
```

I am wondering is there any way to prevent this type of duplicate initialization?
Different types can have a parent class, but how to deal with the list I need to create?
Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a separate attribute for each list you could store them all in a dictionary with the data types as keys. You could then just have a get method to access it.

```
class Something():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_dict = {}

    def add_data(self, data_type: Type, data_value: int):
        try:
            self.list_dict[data_type].append(data_value)
        except KeyError:
            self.list_dict[data_type] = [data_value]

    def get_data(self, data_type)
        return self.list_dict[data_type]
```

Where type_a is the class/data type of the appropriate data type, as returned by type().

OR, as [snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb) points out, perhaps best practice is to use collections' [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to avoid the try/except:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Something():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_dict = defaultdict(list)

    def add_data(self, data_type: Type, data_value: int):
        self.list_dict[data_type].append(data_value)
 
    def get_data(self, data_type)
        return self.list_dict[data_type]
```

Also, as a side note, I would avoid using the variable name type, as it is already a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) in pythons standard library.

Comment: Thank you so much. The second one looks really good to me. :)

Comment: No worries, see my addition about using the variable name type. :-)

Comment: You could avoid the try/except by using a collections.defaultdict

Comment: @FinleyGibson I don't the point of 'type' here, is it something similar to enum or?

Comment: type is an inbuilt function in Python. Calling `type(a)` will return the type of variable a. Try it yourself by doing `print(type(1))` in a fresh script and you should see`int`, as 1 is an integer. Its bad practice to assign variables names which are already defined in pythons standard library, as it can lead to mistakes arising from  confusing the two uses. Even if you remember that you've overwritten the standard type function with a variable called type, it makes code harder to read for a third party, and we try to always write code so that it can be easily read.

Comment: just changing the argument names to something like `data_type` and `data_value` will prevent any such confusion. I am not sure how it would fit in the broader usage of your code, but you may even by able to change `add_data`  to only take one argument `def add_value(self, data_value):`, and then do `data_type = type(value)` to automatically determine the type of the data. But this depends on the intended usage of `add_data`.

Comment: I've modified the code in my answer, to avoid using type as a variable name to illustrate.

Comment: Great, I understand now! Thank you for the help. :)